# How to move physical partition into extended partition?

Tags: partitioning, raspberrypi, fdisk

Given a disk layout like this

```
                                            Disk: /dev/sdc
                                       Size: 119.9 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
                                                 Label: dos, identifier: 0x000efb19

    Device               Boot                   Start              End          Sectors         Size        Id Type
>>  Free space                                   2048             8191             6144           3M                                 
    /dev/sdc1                                    8192          4615234          4607043         2.2G         e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
    /dev/sdc2                                 4615235         29985858         25370624        12.1G         5 Extended
    ├─Free space                              4618240          4620288             2049           1M
    ├─/dev/sdc5                               4620288          4685821            65534          32M        83 Linux
    ├─/dev/sdc6                               4685824          5210109           524286         256M         c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
    └─/dev/sdc7                               5210112         29983811         24773700        11.8G        83 Linux
    /dev/sdc3            *                   29986816         92901375         62914560          30G        83 Linux
    Free space                               92901376        249737215        156835840        74.8G
```

If I wanted to move sdc3 into sdc2 (thus making it sdc8), how would I do that?

Note: The end of sdc7 is the start of sdc3, so there's no need to actually MOVE any data.  This question is just how to change the partition table such that sdc3 is in sdc2

duplicate of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/994063/how-to-move-physical-partition-into-extended-partition)

tl;dr How do I change the partition table without actually editing the data in the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use parted to edit the partition table until it looks like what you want - it would need to mean that you expand the extended partition as well.  Unlike Windows partitioning tools, the regular Linux tools don't wipe the first few KB of a partition (destroying data).  The change to the partition name will mean a different device name so you'll need to account for this in your mount table.  If it's the root or boot partition you'd need to account for it in your initramfs and maybe regenerate grub - all of which can be tricky when you need to be able to boot to it to do it but it's not out of the question.

Make sure you have it backed up in case.

Edit: That said, consider whether you really need to do it as it could reduce flexibility to resize or move in the future - at the moment it's really easy for sdc3 to expand into the free space after it, but if the extended partition ends right after it, you'll have to go into raw partition editing again to do so.

Comment: How would I do what you say in the first sentence (without destroying sdc3)?

Comment: If I try making sdc2 42.1G cfdisk says `Maximum size is 12990808576 bytes.`

Comment: You'd need to drop sdc3 first and recreate it as a logical partition after the extended partition is expanded.  Write down start and end sectors of every partition so you can put it back how it was before if you need to. Last time I was doing this kind of thing, I had whole image backups (with DD) of everything just in case.  It takes a lot longer but I was scared of losing stuff.

Comment: What if I just replaced [original](https://gist.github.com/vegerot/c1c5d86aecc42c90e7a9f8192d0bf0da) with [modified](https://gist.github.com/vegerot/63527f3f989c50d67eb1e4436462611c)?

Comment: Would I need to change more than just the name and the size of `sdc2` (to something that extends it past the end of `sdc8`)?

Comment: First back up current partition table. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdc > PTsdc.txt` While used more to repair gpt partition table, you can use fixparts to convert partitions. You have to follow all the rules of partitions, but it looks like an easy conversion is all you need. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/